# Постоянный редирект Curl

Tags: php, curl

Помогите с решением проблемы пожалуйста.
Если зайти на страницу через браузер, то страница работает.
А если обращаюсь через Curl, то страницу постоянно редиректит.

```
$url = "https://m.vk.com/video-51109251_456239104";

$cookie_file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/VKCOOKIE";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Даже `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` 0, то результат тот же.

Comment: Wireshark'ом сравните запросы

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не понял Вас

Comment: google Wireshark, как погуглите - разбирайтесь как им траффик захватывать. Потом сравнивайте запросы от браузера и от curl.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов спасибо, попробую разобраться, но лучше было бы конечно получить тут правильный ответ, если он есть.

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы вы поняли, что сайт - черный ящик и что у других людей может быть другое поведение по неведомой причине. Решение, которое точно сработает - вести себя через curl в точности также как браузер. Для этого - см. первый комментарий.

Comment: Что ж если не будет больше ответов, то буду смотреть, программу уже поставил, но честно говоря я совсем не понимаю её, посмотрю в ютубе уроки тогда. Надеюсь это даст результат положительный. Спасибо.

Comment: Ютуб не даст положительных результатов, читайте нормальную документацию.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70464/discussion-between--and--).

Comment: а как вы поняли, что страницу постоянно редиректит?

Comment: c `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)` все отлично работает.

Comment: @Jean-Claude но у меня почему-то не работает даже так. Когда я ставлю заголовок `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept-encoding: gzip, deflate',));` тогда страница не обновляется, но при этом на сайте выводятся одни каракули.

Comment: не каракули, а кодировка отличная от ожидаемой вами.